# difference between equating pointers before and after allocation at that address c++

Tags: c++, pointers

A simplified version of what I have is along the lines of

This one fails:

```
myclass* a;
myclass* b;

b=a;

a = new myclass();

*b=x; //fails here
```

This one works

```
myclass* a;
myclass* b;

a = new myclass();

b=a;

*b=x; //works here
```

Why is this?

Comment: Forget about pointers. `int a, b; b = a; a = 10; b++;` vs. `int a, b; a = 10;  b = a; b++;`. First one is UB. Second one sets `b` to 11. Ditto for your code

Comment: What the hell is `x`?

Comment: `*b=x; //fails here` What's `x` actually? Also `b` simply isn't initialized properly at this point, so you might find your Schrödinger's cat lying dead in it's box (you have raised undefined behavior!).

Comment: When you store the address of a new object in `a`, it doesn't automatically update `b`

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

```
myclass* a;
myclass* b;

b=a; // fails here!
```

You are reading the value of an uninitialized variable, which is undefined behavior.  After that all bets are off.

To answer why the second one acts differently, it is because `=` is **NOT algebraic equality** as your question says.  It is *assignment*.  It copies the value from the right-hand side into the variable named by the left-hand side.

You can easily write `x = x + 1;`, which is impossible in algebra, but a perfectly valid assignment.

In computer processors, instructions are evaluated *sequentially*, unlike algebra where all equations remain true throughout the entire proof.

Comment: *Most* computer code--but (for example) in Prolog, you have things that look a bit like assignments, but can be evaluated in relatively arbitrary orders, and are intended to be statements of facts rather than assignments.

Comment: @Jerry: But that has no equivalent in machine code, it's more like data which is analyzed by a solver, than really being code.  The processor fetch-decode-execute cycle is sequential (plus pipelining and branch prediction and speculative execution and a whole bunch of stuff that's supposed to act as-if it is sequential).

Comment: Do my eyes deceive me? It sure looks to me like your answer says "computer code" (which Prolog certainly is), not "machine code" (which your comment seems to discuss).

Answer (score 0):

In the first, you start with `a` pointing to some garbage location. You then assign<sup>1</sup> that address to `b`, so it points to the same garbage location<sup>2</sup>. *Then* you point `a` to newly allocated object of the class. Finally, you try to write to the garbage location that `b` still points at.

In the second, you start with `a` and `b` both pointing to garbage locations, but then you allocate an object, and point `a` at it. Then you assign that address to `b`, so now they both point to the object you just allocated. Finally, you write to that object via `b`.

---

1. For anybody who's having serious trouble with the most basic concepts involved, "assign" means taking the value on the right side of the assignment operator (`=`, in C and C++) and copying it into the location specified on the left side. Some language use a different operator (e.g., `:=` in Pascal) to try to reduce confusion, but with only limited success.
2. Officially at that point it's all undefined behavior, but in reality it makes little difference on most normal processors. In the typical case, copying a garbage bit pattern from one pointer to another can be done, as long as you never try to dereference it.

Comment: Nope.  He starts with `a` uninitialized.  He then tries to read `a`, to store the pointer value into `b`, but the story ends because reading an uninitialized variable is undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Yes, that's covered in the footnote--but contributes essentially nothing to actually understanding what's going on.

Comment: Well, I would argue that any answer that doesn't address the misconception of "equating", as expressed in the title, doesn't lead to actually understanding what is going on.

Comment: @BenVoigt: How often do you think I need to say "assigning" to make it clear that what it does is...assigning?

Comment: Saying "assigning" more times doesn't make clear what "assigning" does.

Comment: @BenVoigt: ...and next you want me to specify "what the definition of 'is' is"?

Comment: That requires presidential dicta... way above our pay grade ;)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is because `b = a` copies the memory address of by value, not by reference. For the first example to work, you would have to do:

```
myclass* a;
myclass*& b = a;

a = new myclass();

*b=x;
```

Answer (score 0):

The assignment `b=a` assigns `b` to have the the *current* value of `a`. `b` is not updated if `a` later changes; it retains the value it was assigned, until it's modified in some other way.

So the first version assigns `b` with the invalid value of the uninitialised `a`. `b` remains invalid when `a` is later assigned with a valid pointer value, and using it gives undefined behaviour. (Strictly speaking, the assignment itself gives undefined behaviour - you're not allowed to use an uninitialised value at all.)

The second assigns `b` with the value of `a` *after* it's been given a valid value; so both have the same value, pointing to the same object, and both are usable.

Answer (score 0):

In first example you are trying to initialize `b` with `a`, which is uninitialized, then dereference that uninitialized variable.
In second case you initialize `a`, then initialize `b` with `a`, then dereference that valid memory location, what is correct.